# $\big(y∧x)∨(¬x∧y)\big)$ is same as?

Tags: calculus

$\big(y∧x)∨(¬x∧y)\big)$ is same as?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: hi, welcome to math stackexchange..You can think of using truth table if you want precise way

Comment: It is obviously a tautology.

Comment: @leonard why can't we use associative law to prove ??

Comment: A simple check is enough: if $z$ is True, then the left part is True. If $z$ is False, then the right part is True. Being a disjunction, in both cases the formula is True.

Answer (score 1):

By applying associative laws, we get that

$\big((y∧x)∨z\big)∨\big(¬z∨(¬x∧y)\big)=\\=(y∧x)∨(z∨¬z)∨(¬x∧y)=\\=(y∧x)∨T∨(¬x∧y)=\\
=T$

where $\;T=\text{True}\;.$